# Is there a way in pandas to remove duplicates from within a series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XOyq.png) which has some duplicate tags separated by commas in the "Tags" column, is there a way to remove the duplicate strings from the series. I want the output in 400 to have just Museum, Drinking, Shopping.

I can't split on a comma & remove them because there are some tags in the series that have similar words like for example: [Museum, Art Museum, Shopping] so splitting and dropping multiple museum strings would affect the unique 'Art Museum' string.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6AII.png)

Comment: "splitting and dropping multiple museum strings would affect the unique 'Art Museum' string." Depending on how you do it, no, it wouldn't. Split on comma, take a set. having said that, this looks like a pretty unhelpful column if kept in its current format unless you just wish to use it for display.

Comment: Can you please upload a small sample of your dataframe and desired output?

Comment: please show a simple of your original data and what do you expect.

Comment: It's better that you include your data as text than as picture.

Comment: I have made some changes that provide two pictures with the first being original dataframe and the last being the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that removes duplicates from a given string. Then apply this function to your column Tags.

```
def remove_dup(strng):
    '''
     Input a string and split them 
    '''
    return ', '.join(list(dict.fromkeys(strng.split(', '))))


df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: remove_dup(x))
```

DEMO:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'Tags':["Museum, Art Museum, Shopping, Museum",'Drink, Drink','Shop','Visit'],'Country':['USA','USA','USA', 'USA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: remove_dup(x))
df
```

Output:

```
    Tags                          Country
0   Museum, Art Museum, Shopping    USA
1   Drink                           USA
2   Shop                            USA
3   Visit                           USA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split by comma and convert to a `set()`,which removes duplicates, after removing leading/trailing white space with `str.strip()`. Then, you can `df.apply()` this to your column.

```
df['Tags']=df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set([y.strip() for y in x.split(',')])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without some code example, I've thrown together something that would work.

```
import pandas as pd
test = [['Museum', 'Art Museum', 'Shopping', "Museum"]]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df[0] = test
df[0]= df.applymap(set)
```

> ```
> Out[35]: 
>                                 0
> 0  {Museum, Shopping, Art Museum}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that avoids `apply`

```
# in your code just s = df['Tags']
s = pd.Series(['','', 'Tour',
               'Outdoors, Beach, Sports', 
               'Museum, Drinking, Drinking, Shopping'])

(s.str.split(',\s+', expand=True)
      .stack()
      .reset_index()
      .drop_duplicates(['level_0',0])
      .groupby('level_0')[0]
      .agg(','.join)
)
```

Output:

```
level_0
0                            
1                            
2                        Tour
3       Outdoors,Beach,Sports
4    Museum,Drinking,Shopping
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

there maybe mach fancier way doing these kind of stuffs.
but will do the job.

make it lower-case

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].str.lower()
```

split every row in tags col by comma it will return a list of string

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].str.split(',')
```

map function str.strip to every element of list (remove trailing spaces).
apply set function return set of current words and remove duplicates

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(lambda x: set(map(str.strip , x)))
```